# Using WebClient Class inside a Visual Web Part

Tags: web-part

I am trying to use the WebClient Class inside a Visual Web Part (via a User Control code behind class). When I want to run the web part I always get:

> Asynchronous operations are not
>   allowed in this context. Page starting
>   an asynchronous operation has to have
>   the Async attribute set to true and an
>   asynchronous operation can only be
>   started on a page prior to
>   PreRenderComplete event.

How can I avoid this. I know that I can set the async property to true on a normal ASP.NET page. But how can I achieve this inside SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 1):

At what point in the page lifecycle are you using your WebClient object? Not inside the Render method I hope? :)

If you want to set the Async property of the page, have a look at [Page.AsyncMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.asyncmode%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

You should be able to set this.Page.AsyncMode on the Load event (in code-behind) of your Visual WebPart.

Answer (score 0):

I am developing a sharepoint webpart and trying to make async web service calls, I get the "Asynchronous operations are not allowed in this context. Page starting an asynchronous operation..." message. I was trying to add Page.AsyncMode = true; in the OnLoad of the webPart class however my Page doesnt have the AsyncMode property?

any ideas why I dont have the property ?